Robot framework always fails a test case
I have created the following robot file and the pass string file
*** Settings ***
Documentation   Test cases
Library         test.py
Variables       EcuSanityTest_PassString.py
*** Test Cases ***
ECU_SANITY_TEST_1
          parse_logs    ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_LOG_FILE}      ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_1_PASS}

ECU_SANITY_TEST_2
          parse_logs    ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_LOG_FILE}      ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_2_PASS}

ECU_SANITY_TEST_3
          parse_logs    ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_LOG_FILE}      ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_3_PASS}

ECU_SANITY_TEST_4
          parse_logs    ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_LOG_FILE}      ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_4_PASS}

ECU_SANITY_TEST_5
          parse_logs    ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_LOG_FILE}      ${ECU_SANITY_TEST_5_PASS}

EcuSanityTest_PassString.py
ECU_SANITY_TEST_1_PASS='''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_1:PASS
'''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_2_PASS='''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_2:PASS
'''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_3_PASS='''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_3:PASS
'''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_4_PASS='''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_4:PASS
'''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_5_PASS='''
ECU_SANITY_TEST_5:PASS
'''

This is the test.py file
import os
import sys

def parse_logs(logFile, passText):
    passStringFound = False
    with open(logFile, "r") as fp_log:
        lines = fp_log.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            split_lines = line.split()
            if passText in split_lines:
                passStringFound = True
                break

    if passStringFound == False:
        raise AssertionError('Test Failed')

the test log file contains the expected pass text. However the robot framework reports all the test cases as failed
log.txt
ECU_SANITY_TEST_1:PASS
ECU_SANITY_TEST_3:PASS
ECU_SANITY_TEST_5:PASS

robot output
==============================================================================
EcuSanityTest :: Test cases
==============================================================================
ECU_SANITY_TEST_1                                                     | FAIL |
Test Failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECU_SANITY_TEST_2                                                     | FAIL |
Test Failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECU_SANITY_TEST_3                                                     | FAIL |
Test Failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECU_SANITY_TEST_4                                                     | FAIL |
Test Failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECU_SANITY_TEST_5                                                     | FAIL |
Test Failed
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EcuSanityTest :: Test cases                                           | FAIL |
5 tests, 0 passed, 5 failed
==============================================================================

Can anyone please help me understand why the robot framework always reports the test as failed?
i have tried returning true/false values from the test.py script but the problem still remains. i expect that the robot framework reports the tests 1,3 and 5 as passed and the rest as failed

Because you have split variables in "EcuSanityTest_PassString.py" into three lines, they are actually "\nECU_SANITY_TEST_1:PASS\n". Notice newlines before and after. I guess that these do not match the ones in your log file. My recommendation is to define them in one line without newlines.
